# how is the target of $\text{tor}_n^R(A,\ )$ related to $\mathbf{Ab}$?

Tags: abelian-groups, functors, derived-functors, torsion-groups

I do not follow in the snippet below (taken from Advanced Modern Algebra, Rotman, Vol. 2,page 277,3rd edition) how it is meant that the target of
$$\text{tor}_n^R(A,\ )$$
may be **smaller** or **larger** then $\mathbf{Ab}$ if $R=\mathbb{Q}$
or $R=\mathbb{Z}G$, respectively.
I would say that it is not strictly larger in the case of $R=\mathbb{Z}G$
since it is **exactly** $\mathbf{Ab}$ here (i.e. $\mathbf{Ab}$ are just $\mathbb{Z}-$modules). I also cannot understand why it is smaller when $R=\mathbb{Q}$ ? *I think that I'm confusing something here.
Any detailed hint please ?*

[image]

Comment: For a commutative ring $R$, the tensor product of two $R$-modules is an $R$-module. The same applies to the derived Tor functors. If $R$ is non-commutative, then the tensor product of a right $R$-module and left $R$-module is in general just an Abelian group, so in this case the Tor functors spit out Abelian groups.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But $\mathbb{Q}$ **is** a commutative ring and still they claim that it is not $\mathbf{Ab}$. Also, I'm not a native speaker and I do not follow the phrasal verb *spit out*.

Comment: The category of $\Bbb Q$-module is a subcategory of that of Abelian groups, so is "smaller" in some sense.